# Is it possible to to define a re-usable path operation?

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, aws-api-gateway

We are adding CORS support to our Swagger API which includes defining an options operation per path. Since this is boiler-plate code we want to define the option operation once in the definitions section like so

```
"definitions":{  
 "CORS":{ .. }
 }
```

And then reference the operation in our paths like so

```
"paths":{  
      "/system/info":{  
        "options" : {
           "$ref": "#/definitions/CORS"
       }
    }
}
```

This does not seem to work when we upload the swagger definition. What is the proper way to accomplish our goal of defining a path operation once and then re-using it across paths?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reference an entire path to an external location:

```
"paths": {
  "/system/info": {
    "$ref": "cors.json"
  }
}
```

but not an individual http method.  In addition, the spec doesn't allow for a relative reference for a path--you'll have to put it in a separate document.

See [here](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#pathItemObject) for information on the path item object, and [here](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#swagger-object) for the top-level swagger object.